# PHP SELECT/Show last[number] items inserted in database

Tags: php

In my DB I have some "documents" which contain more items, I'm inserting that from my dashboard.

The thing is **;** when displaying, the method requires a value in my case it's `$id`.
Right now I am using `rand()` with hardcoded range to show different "documents".

This is how it looks **:**

```
        <?php

        $num = rand(1,10);
        $post->showSmallPost($num);

        ?>
```

**Let's say i want to have three of these on HTML page. But instead of this `rand()` I want to show the last three ID imported to table.** *So that is my question, how to do it?*

This is a method `showSmallPost()`**:**

```
public function showSmallPost($id){

    $connection = new Db();
    $conn = $connection->connect();

    $image = new Image();
    $imgC = $image->showSmallImg($id);

    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM post WHERE id = ?");
    $query->bind_param('i', $id);

    $query->execute();

    $result = $query->get_result();

    if($result->num_rows > 0) {

        if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

            $this->id = $row['id'];
            $this->title = $row['title'];
            $this->description = $row['description'];

            echo "<div class=\"col-md-4 text-center\" style=\"margin-top: 5px;\">";

            echo <<<EOT

                    <a href="news.php?post=$id">
                        $imgC
                    </a>

                    <h4 class="news-title">$this->title</h4>
                    <p class="news-para">$this->description</p>

                EOT;

            echo "</div>";

        }

    }

}
```

And yes, this `showSmallImg()` is just doing his job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add Sort to the Query.
You don't need to pass a random `$id` to the function.
You can change the SQL statement to:

```php
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,1");
```

Also you can get 3 Documents in a Single Query With,

```php
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,3");
```

You can even optimize the query to run faster,

```php
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, title, description FROM post ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 0,3");
```

Also, rather than using HTML inside echo, you can create a multidimensional array of your preferred structure or use the one that the sql query returns. 
And make use of `foreach` method and only print the Values inside the array with PHP and leave HTML as it is.

It will generate more cleaner code.

For Example:

```php
<div class=col-md-4 text-center" style="margin-top: 5px;">
    <a href="news.php?post=<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $imgC; ?></a>
    <h4 class="news-title"><?php echo $this->title; ?></h4>
    <p class="news-para"><?php echo $this->description ?></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the last id from the database, and create a for loop decrementing it.

```
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT MAX(id) AS last_id FROM post");
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $lastId = $row['last_id'];

    for ($i = $lastId; $i > $lastId - 3; $i--)
    {
        $post->showSmallPost($i);
    }
```

Alternatively, you can use the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` statements to get what you want.

```
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT id FROM post ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3");
    $query->execute();
    $result = $query->get_result();
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $post->showSmallPost($row['id']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding it right then you want to fetch the latest n records from a table and to do that you need to have a field like `createdAt`. Then you can write a query which will fetch the n records and order result by this `createdAt` field in descending order.

Your query then will look something like this

```
select * from posts order by createdAt desc limit 5;
```

This will give you the latest 5 records inserted into the table.